# Formatting Eighth Notes in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

These are the notes that LilyPond is producing

[image: Connected eighth notes]

How do I make the notes look like this instead?
(I edited this image, sorry if the last eighth note looks bad)

[image: Unconnected eighth notes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
c8\> d! c d c r8\!
```

try

```
c8[\> d!] c[ d] c r8\!
```

The square brackets override LilyPond's defaults in beaming quavers.

### Addendum

Refer to LilyPond's [documentation regarding changing the default beaming behavior](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/beams#setting-automatic-beam-behavior) for more info on how to customize how you want LilyPond to beam the quavers.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the beam start and ends with `[` and `]`:

```
%%  APPROACH 1  %%
\relative c'' {
    \time 3/4
        c8[\> d!] c[ d] c r8\!
}
```

---

If you want to simply override the beam exceptions (3/4 has an exception that prefers up to 6 quavers per beam)

```
%%  APPROACH 2  %%
\relative c'' { 
    \time 3/4
    \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()       
        c8\> d! c d c r8\!      
}
```

See:  http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/beams#setting-automatic-beam-behavior

---

If you want more manipulatable code that overrides all the time signature settings, so that the the beams appear in your preferred locations:

```
%%  APPROACH 3  %%
\relative c'' { 
    \overrideTimeSignatureSettings
        3/4        % timeSignatureFraction
        1/4        % baseMomentFraction
        #'(1 1 1)  % beatStructure
        #'()       % beamExceptions
    \time 3/4
        c8\> d! c d c r8\!      
}
```

See:  http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-rhythms#time-signature